# Find out module slowing down emacs

Tags: emacs

I have lots of modules loaded in emacs. With some files, things get very slow. I would like to find out which module is the culprit. How could I debug this in emacs? Are there any debug settings / configuration parameters which could help me in logging the activity that emacs is performing while I move / edit in the active buffer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may find useful doing a  <kbd>M-x profiler-start</kbd>.  Use mode cpu when asked.  After a while, type <kbd>M-x profile-report</kbd> and take a look to the findings.  It is easy navigating through them.

Other than that, you always have the "binary search" cheapo-approach of commenting in and out fractions of your init file to find out who is slowing things :-)

Comment: Ah, another new feature in 24.3! You can also use the `elp` library which has been around for longer.

Comment: The `profiler-start` is not available in stock emacs. Any idea where can I get this?

Comment: It is available only on recent emacs versions, afaik.  You may want to give a try to `elp` instead, as suggested by gonvaled... but I cannot remember if it can profile "everything" (as opposed to specific functions or packages).

Comment: gonvaled: Well 24.3 is the current stable release, so I'm pretty sure that counts as "stock emacs"; but as indicated you can use `elp` on older versions: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsLispProfiler

Comment: And having now had a quick play with `profiler`, I would say that it is complementary to `elp` rather than a replacement for it. `profiler` for CPU and memory usage; `elp` for timing (which will include time spent waiting for external processes to respond, which might be the critical information in some instances).

Comment: @juanleon: I have emacs 23.4.1, and `profiler` is *not* available. Do you know if  I can download it from somewhere? The [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Profiling.html) talks about a built-in profiler, but my version does not have it

Comment: I am afraid that this documentation points to last emacs version.  Emacs 23.x has elp built in, but elp module works by instrumentalizing  code (so you need to know in advance what to instrumentalize), and it does not substitute the more modern profiler (but complements it).  So, if you cannot grab (doing a local install) a more recent emacs, I would go with the binary-search approach on your setup (plus site local setup).